# EXPO Go App not loading up project when trying to scan using different phone

Tags: react-native, expo, expo-go

It seems I've encountered a snag while testing my React Native app using Expo Go. Initially, scanning the app with a phone lacking a SIM card worked fine. However, when I tried using another phone on the same Wi-Fi network, that had a SIM card the app refused to load. My own phone with a SIM works obviously since that's what I've been using to test this in the beginning.

I tried Switching to an old, deprecated method called tunnel managed to load the app, but whenever I attempted a POST request (triggered by a button on the front end), I consistently received an error in the catch block.

I put e app.(cors()) in my index.js file

I've even put both phones in the verified call section on twilio.

Comment: If you catch the error, could you provide us with details of the error?

Comment: Please define "refused to load".  As @Takkie requests: please provide the error on the device.  If the app is crashing, consider getting the native/system logs to see what the specific exception message is.